# WPF hit testing a rectangular area

Tags: wpf

I have a WrapPanel containing an arbitrary number of jagged sized elements.  I'd like to implement drag select for my items.

It seems pretty obvious how to HitTest for a point, but how can I find all items within a rectangular area?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608753.aspx) with a [GeometryHitTestParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometryhittestparameters.aspx) argument and a [HitTestFilterCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.hittestfiltercallback.aspx) that checks if a Visual is a direct child of the Panel.

Something like this:

```
var selectedElements = new List<DependencyObject>();

var rect = new RectangleGeometry(...);
var hitTestParams = new GeometryHitTestParameters(rect);

var resultCallback = new HitTestResultCallback(
    result => HitTestResultBehavior.Continue);

var filterCallback = new HitTestFilterCallback(
    element =>
    {
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) == panel)
        {
            selectedElements.Add(element);
        }
        return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
    });

VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(
    panel, filterCallback, resultCallback, hitTestParams);
```

---

It looks a little complicated, but the `HitTestFilterCallback` is necessary to get all Visuals in the visual tree, not only those that actually got hit. For example if your panel contains Label controls, the `HitTestResultCallback` will only be called for the Border and TextBlock child Visuals of each Label.

Answer (score -1):

The option for controlling hit test visibility is the `IsHitTestVisible` property. This property allows you to control hit test visibility regardless of the brush with which the UIElement is rendered.

Also, You want to set the Fill to Transperent

```
 <Rectangle  Width="200" Height="200" Margin="170,23,12,35" Fill="Transparent" IsHitTestVisible="True"   />
```