# How can I achieve draw rectangle to select in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

These days I wanna add a file select feature in my program.

I want to achieve select the file by drawing a rectangle with the mouse, just like the windows file explorer below:
[image]

In my opinion, I should use a `WrapPanel` as a container, and then add `CheckBoxs` which rewrote `ControlTemplate`.

I have found some incomplete tutorial, just like:[Drag selection box in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107824/drag-selection-box-in-wpf)

Now I can draw the blue rectangle with my mouse by using the `Adorner`.

However, I don't know how to get to know which CheckBoxs are in the rectangle.

What's more, I don't know whether my opinion by using `WrapPanel` and `CheckBox` is a good choice for this.

Could you please give me a suggestion or a sample? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, is this what you might be looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838163/click-and-drag-selection-box-in-wpf

Comment: @ZarX It is something different. The way you provided is base on Canvas which can not arrange children items one by one with Row and Column while WrapPanel can.

Comment: @ZarX And also, File Explorer is selecting the items while you drawing the rectangle by mouse in real-time. It is an ordeal for performance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click and drag selection box in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838163/click-and-drag-selection-box-in-wpf)

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs The topic is the same as the comment of ZarX. However, as I said above, Canvas can't arrange children's items while WrapPanel can.

Comment: If its mainly the detection of which items the rectangle has contained - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832037/wpf-hit-testing-a-rectangular-area maybe?

Comment: Incidentally it is possible to place items in the canvas wherever you want, but its definitely a lot more work.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs Let me try your ways. I have another idea by using System.Drawing.Rectangle.Contains to detect it while it is a winform method.